# What is format of Google Drive's FileID ? I need to find out whether new File has been uploaded to my drive or not using API's

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

If FileID follows a particular format like new file has higher values or lower values I can keep track of the old values and find out whether I hace uploaded a new File in drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File ID is just a random string - there is no format.

You are taking the wrong approach. Look at the changes resource https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes

Comment: So how Do I find the new files added to my drive. If there is something for reference it would be very useful do you know any ??

Comment: Suppose if I am having an app which user needs to be notified when new files are added what would you do ??

Answer (score 10):

The format is a 264 bit number

```
bit 0   5 6             261 261 263
+--------+-----------------+-------+
| 110101 | 256 RANDOM BITS | 00    |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
```

url safe base64 encoded as

```
/1[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{42}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]/
```

You can store just the random part as a `Byte[32]` but it is safer to treat it as a random string as this may change at any time

Comment: Any ideas what that 110101 or 00 at the end are about?

Comment: @SafaAlai the `110101` is so that all drive ids start with "1" when encoded as base64, because [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes 6 bits at a time and it encodes `110101` as "1". This is (probably) done so that you can tell at a glance that some base64 sequence you're looking at is definitely not a drive id if it doesn't start with "1".

Comment: Most likely the "1" at the beginning is intended as a version number to enable new future formats that will not be confused with the current format.