# What is the format of a folder ID in Google Drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

My question is similar to [What is format of Google Drive's FileID ? I need to find out whether new File has been uploaded to my drive or not using API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151920/what-is-format-of-google-drives-fileid-i-need-to-find-out-whether-new-file-ha) but I want to know the format of a folder ID in Google Drive, the one that appears in the URL bar when you open a folder in your Google drive, the thing after `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/<this part>`.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive folder id doesn't have a specific guaranteed format. This (apparent format which really isn't a format) has changed in the past and may change again.

Trying to create any kind of local verification of this will be futile.

The best option would be to do a [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and test if you get a response.  This will work better as it will also verify that the user has access to the file as well as testing that its a valid file id format.

Any (regex) attempt to verify the file id wouldn't really verify it as its not going to test if the user has access.

Answer (score 0):

A folder ID starts with a `1` followed by 32 [base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded digits, except unlike base64 the `+` is replaced by `-` and `/` is replaced by `_`. You can use the following regex:

```
/^1[A-Za-z0-9-_]{32}$/
```